# Delay in NIOS 2 Assembly

Tags: assembly, delay, nios

Description:
I am making a ready set go! program in NIOS 2 assembly. The flow should look like this:

```
start  
  |  
One LED  
delay 1 Sec  
  |  
Four LED  
delay 3 Sec  
  |  
Eight LED  
Go!
```

Question:
I don't know how to program a delay in Nios 2 Assembly. I can't find a good example and I am at a loss.

My Work:
The code below is compliable in the Altera Monitor Program. I started to experiment with timers and could not produce anything useful. See Blocked section in code.

My Code:

```
.data
.equ TIMER_BASE, 0x10002000
.equ PERIOD, 0x1111ffff
.equ DELAY, 20
.equ LED, 0x10000010

.text
.global _start
_start:


movia r4, TIMER_BASE
movi r5, 6
movia r2, PERIOD #load initial timer values
stwio r2, 8(r4)
srli r2, r2, 16
stwio r2, 12(r4)
stwio r5, 4(r4) #start the timer
movi r6, DELAY #delay


oneLED:
movi r14, 0b10000000    #turn on One LED
movia r15, LED
stw r14, 0(r15)
br fourLED

##############

DELAY:
    subi r6,r6,1       #subtract 1 from delay
    bne r6,r0, DELAY #continue subtracting if delay not elapsed
    br DELAY        #delay elapsed, redo the LOOP

##############

fourLED:
movi r14, 0b11110000    #turn on Four LEDs
movia r15, LED
stw r14, 0(r15)
br eightLED

eightLED:
movi r14, 0b11111111    #turn on Eight LEDs
movia r15, LED
stw r14, 0(r15)
br oneLED
```

Please help by giving me an example of delay code. or by fixing my code. Also please provide constructive comments so that I may understand your logic. Thanks

Comment: _"[give] me an example of delay code. or [fix] my code"_ is a really poor "question". Does your target hardware include a timer? If so, use it. If not, try counting clock cycles.

Comment: there is a timer it is 50 Mhz. I would use it except I don't know how. I would appreciate specific examples as I don't know how to do what I need to do.

Answer (score 4):

Below is an example

```
delay:      movia r2, 25000000
wasteTime:  subi  r2,r2, 1
            bne   r2, r0, wasteTime
            ret
```

now to calculate how much delay the subroutine above has:

We know cpu clock=50MHz
each instruction takes about 1 cpu clock

Time of each instruction= 1/f= 1/50MHz = 20 ns

so in the subroutine above movia sub-divides to 2 instruction by the compiler, the loop wasteTime has 2 instructions (subi, bne)

so:

delay= (2 + 2X25000000 + 1)X 20ns = 1 second

I hope this helps..